# Getting month and fiscal year from columns SAS

Tags: date, sas, proc-sql, yearmonth

I have a table with the following type of data

| FISCAL_YEAR | MTH | Month_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FY2018 | 6 | JUN |
| FY2017 | 5 | MAY |
| FY2022 | 10 | OCT |

I want to get current fiscal year (i.e. FY2023 for this instance but FY2024 next year) and 1 month previous (i.e. currently MTH = 7 and/or Month_Name = 'JUL'). How do I get that in SAS PROC SQL?

Comment: I can't understand your goal.  Can you explain more?  The data you showed has fiscal year already.  When you say you want to get the current fiscal year, do you mean the fiscal year at date-time the program is run?  What is your definition for fiscal year?

Comment: Yes, basically I want to filter out the fiscal year the time program is run. For example since the current fiscal year is FY2023, I want to select the rows having FY2023.

Comment: If you want to filer on fiscal_year just use a WHERE clause.   If you want calculate the current fiscal year based on today's date you need to explain what the rules are for determining the interval covered by a fiscal year.  We cannot help unless you show more months and include the actual year in addition to the fiscal year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not clear on your question but...

If you want to calculate the current fiscal year, you can use INTNX with an offset.  The following will calculate current fiscal year, using Oct 1 as fiscal year cutpoint:

```
%let FY= %sysfunc(year(%sysfunc(intnx(year.10, %sysfunc(today()), 0, e)))) ;
%let PriorMonth= %sysfunc(month(%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(today()),-1,b)))) ;

%put &=FY &=PriorMonth ;
```

Returns:

```
FY=2023 PRIORMONTH=7
```

So if you like that, then in your PROC SQL you can use a WHERE clause like:

```
where Fiscal_Year="FY&FY" and MTH=&PriorMonth
```